# assigning a Value in Set accssor Instead of using value keyword

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, properties, initialization

I am wondering why this code works fine and comiler doesnt generate any errors or warnings?

```
class Program
{
    static int _value;
    static int MyValue
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = 5; }
    }


    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Program.MyValue); //This line print 0 (defoult value of int variables)and its normal 
        Program.MyValue = 10; //after calling the Set accssor we will see that
        Console.WriteLine(Program.MyValue); //The result is 5
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

is this any usefull or special thing? or could it be a technic in Property initialization? thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
 It seems what we have here is a *Readonly Property with defoult value* am I right?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. It can't give you a warning or error because you can do what you like in the set implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set-accessor is nothing other than a method with a parameter, the "value"-parameter. It's up to the method what it does and what it does not.

```
void Set__MyValue(int value){
  _value=5;
}
```

Comment: @siamak: THe code I posted is the code the compiler converts the setter to. In your case, the Set__MyValue is called and the value parameter contains an integer value of 10. However in the Set__MyValue method, this parameter is not used further but 5 is assigned to your member variable "_value". That means that every time you set any value to the MyValue-property, 5 is assigned to the member-variable _value. Setting a value to your property is something like a reset.

Comment: :thanks for the comment ,I got it and before you post it I deleted my comment . anyway thanks for clarifying me

Answer (score 1):

The code is valid C#, so wouldn't cause errors or warnings.

Code in getters and setters can be anything, so can't really be statically checked - even if you do something strange like ignore the value passed into the setter, that might be exactly the right thing for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `set` statement is actually just a convenient way of specifying a full method (i.e. `set_MyValue(int value)`) all the normal rules of functions apply. In particular, there is no obligation to use the parameters if you don't want to.

While your example is contrived, there are plenty of situations where it makes sense to ignore the `value` passed in. For example, suppose you wanted to make sure a particular `string` property was never null. You might do something like this:

```
private string _myProp = string.Empty;
public string MyProp
{
    get
    {
        return _myProp;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            _myProp = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        _myProp = value;
    }
}
```

We ignore `value` if we want to, and don't otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The property will be converted as 2 different methods in IL(one for set the value and the other is to return the value) and ignoring a parameter is valid in a method!

You can check this by using the tool `ildasm.exe`(which comes with Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

This code is pretty valid and also can be usefull in certain scenarious . If you immagine that you want raise an event/WPF command on `_value` changing, log that stuff, do any other meaningful for you stuff there.  Having this kind of management setting the `_value` directly will cause "silent" assignment, setting this `_value` via property can cause  notifications.

I will never do something like this honestly, cause it's confusional and not clear for someone who doesn't really understand your code, but by the way it's kind of "solution" too.

Regards.

Comment: its great if you could give some code for your idea,thank u very much.